# Can "our" be used with "singular subject"?

Tags: pronouns, possessives

I doubt that this sentence is correct.

> Tutorials Point (I) Pvt. Ltd provides no guarantee regarding the accuracy, timeliness or completeness of **our** website or its contents including this tutorial.

I asked the writer/author and he said the sentence is correct.

I think he should have used **its** and not **our**. Am I right or wrong? If someone knows why please explain why **our** is correct and give more examples.

Comment: If you use *its*, then the second *its* will refer to the supplier.

Comment: @Mick. Can you explain it more?

Comment: I don't have the expertise to provide a full answer. However, if you remove "of our website*, you may see what I'm getting at. With *our*, *its* refers to the website. If you use *its* twice, then the conjunction *or* becomes ambiguous.

Comment: Whose website is it? Yours, or Tutorials Point (I) Pvt. Ltd?

Comment: @Mick  of course: **Tutorials Point (I) Pvt. Ltd** I am reading their e-books. And this sentence is at the first page. I am not an expert in English but still I think **our** is wrong

Comment: "our website" refers to the website that belongs to us.  Consider "My husband and I like our car" (we only have one car, and it belongs to us). Also "my husband and I like our car and its color" --"its" refers to the color of the car.  The color is a characteristic of the car.

Comment: @Xanne I am aware of this rule. Since you used **and** between **two** subjects than you can use **our** to refer to both of them. It is correct.. But this sentence that I posted here has a single subject

Comment: But there's more than one object.

Comment: The use of the third person singular form of the verb _provide_ together with the word _our_ is what makes the sentence wrong. If the verb is changed from _provides_ to _provide_ there is no inconsistency since the company name would then become a plural entity and _our_ would be a suitable pronoun. With the use of the third person singular form of the verb the OP is right that the pronoun should be _its_ to match. Either approach is correct but consistency is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question asks about the use of the *plural* pronoun *our* to refer to the company.

> The use of plural pronouns to represent collective nouns—such as company, team, division, department, or unit—works fine to emphasize the individuals in the organization.
>   [- Business Writing](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2015/10/should-a-company-be-it-or-we-.html)

They provide the following examples (emphasis in original):

> - *We* at Company X wish to express *our* sincere appreciation for Company Y’s continued support.
> - Brooks & Rice have lost their lease. They are now looking for a new location.  (citing *Gregg*)

The link goes on to cite The Gregg Reference Manual, The Chicago Manual of Style, and The Associated Press Stylebook to support both singular and plural agreement in these situations.

You can think of the company as the collection of individuals it represents (whether shareholders, directors, officers and/or staff, etc). It's this collection that asserts the lack of a guarantee in your example. Since the writer is writing on behalf of the company, using a first-person pronoun works.

On the other hand, you are also free to consider the company as a monolithic 'individual', so calling the website '*its* website' as you propose is also ok. In that case, however, you need to be careful to distinguish whether 'its contents' referred to later are the company's contents or the website's contents.

You should, however, be consistent - either "provide ... our" or "provide*s* ... its", but not "provides ... our". The link above notes this with the following problematic example (the asterisks below denote a problematic portion - both should be singular or both should be plural):

> - Company X *wishes to express *our sincere appreciation for Company Y’s continued support.

In my opinion, "Company X *wish*" sounds decidedly odd. I'd prefer either "*We* at Company X *wish" or "Company X *wishes* ... *its*".

Comment: I have no problem with considering a **company name** as a **plural name**. It is acceptable. But what about the **verb**? If we say *we* is correct then the verb is not.

Comment: @k-five I'll add note about consistency.

Comment: @k-five *Done*.

Comment: very good link.

Comment: @k-five Thanks. I see you've raised the question there as well now :) . Just a note about how it sounds - the original phrasing sounded fine to me on first presentation. Technically, there's a problem with agreement, but it sounds ok here. Perhaps it could be argued that the monolithic company *provides* no guarantees of the website its members (hence "our") maintain.

Comment: The ebook have been written in British Grammar and I am learning US. I noted that it is **okay** with British Grammar. They are allowed to use this inconsistency.

Comment: @k-five Good ol' BrE :) . Note that if the sentence has no context, the "our" might not even be the company. Suppose C commissioned W to make a website. Then C could say, "W provides no guarantees about our (C's) website ...". Or to pick a more relevant example, *Stack Exchange provides no guarantees about the accuracy of our (the community's) answers*. :)

Comment: You are right. In:  *Stack Exchange provides no guarantees about the accuracy of our answers*. **Stack** is separated from its **users**. We (= users of Stack) are "We" but **Stack** is "It". But Tutorials-point and its ebooks and its website and its contents are the same. We are not belong to "Stack" but these ebooks are belong to that company. Anyway I am waiting for Lynn answer. :)

Comment: This answer seems to assume British English. In US English we never use plural *verbs* with a company name, but we nonetheless often use plural *pronouns*; something like "Mozilla has released a new version of their Firefox browser" is the US equivalent of British "Mozilla have [...]".

Comment: @ruakh I don't think it's a BrE / AmE thing. "Mozilla *have* ..." sounds odd (see the closing sentence in my answer). I'm not entirely satisfied with my own answer, though I don't object to the presence of "our", even with singular agreement of the company's name with *provides*. I just don't have a good enough reason *why* it's fine with 'split' agreement (so to speak).

Comment: @Lawrence: It's certainly a BrE/AmE thing at least to some extent; in AmE \*"Mozilla have" is completely ungrammatical, not just "odd". And examples like \*"the Government have", which is likewise completely ungrammatical in AmE, is nonetheless well-attested in BrE. If it even remotely occurred to you to suggest "provide" as an option, then you're thinking in BrE.

Comment: @ruakh Your pronouncements (immediately above) do not seem to agree with those of the editors of Gregg and CMOS. Would you say you have greater authority? Or should you perhaps retract?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't think my comments disagree with the *Chicago Manual of Style*. Perhaps you are smoking something? (As for the *Gregg Reference Manual*, this is the first I've heard of it, but if it really claims that AmE speakers use plural verb agreement in a way that we don't, then that's a mistake and you should take it up with its editor.)

Answer (score 2):

Summary:

The use of ***our*** is not strictly correct, but as noted in comments the use of ***its*** can become ambiguous in meaning. However, the verb ***provides*** is in the singular form which does not fit with ***our***.

---

Further thinking:

> Tutorials Point (I) Pvt. Ltd provides no guarantee regarding the accuracy, timeliness or completeness of our website or its contents including this tutorial.

Consider as an alternative to fit with the use of ***our***:

> We provide no guarantee regarding the accuracy, timeliness or completeness of our website or its contents including this tutorial.

and so

> We (Tutorials Point (I) Pvt. Ltd) provide no guarantee regarding the accuracy, timeliness or completeness of our website or its contents including this tutorial.

So instead of the pronoun ***we*** they use the company name, but then to fit with the use of ***our*** they should actually use ***provide*** instead of ***provides***.

Using the singular form ***provides*** with the company name (which is often regarded as a singular entity) then, despite ambiguity, ***our*** should be replaced by ***its***, but it is also common for a company name to be treated as plural which works with ***our*** but not with ***provides***.

> Tutorials Point (I) Pvt. Ltd provides no guarantee regarding the accuracy, timeliness or completeness of its website or its contents including this tutorial.

compared to a person where there is not ambiguity:

> John Smith provides no guarantee regarding the accuracy, timeliness or completeness of ***his*** website or its contents including this tutorial.

So, to fit with ***provides*** they should really use ***its***, or a common alternative ***their*** which is also often used for both singular and plural references.

Comment: I agree with you if the verb **provides** was plural. But It is singular too. Since **verb** is  singular anyone who reads the sentence quickly will think that the **subject** is singular. In fact if we agree **our** is correct then we should say **provides** is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I have made some edits with the aim of adding clarity.

Comment: This answer seems to assume British English. In US English we never use plural *verbs* with a company name, but we nonetheless often use plural *pronouns*; something like "Mozilla has released a new version of their Firefox browser" is the US equivalent of British "Mozilla have [...]".